# Trying to create an event calendar using the datepicker javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, calendar, datepicker

I am attempting to use the javascript datepicker to help in showing a calendar and being able to select a date to add/view/edit an event on that date.

I currently have a view that shows the datepicker calender in a div

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Event Calendar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
      $(function () {
          $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a model Todays events that will show the events for the day

```
namespace TryEvents2.Models
{
    public class TodaysEventsViewModel
    {
        public List<Event> events;
    }
}
```

a model for the specific events

```
namespace TryEvents2.Models
{
    [Bind(Exclude = "Id")]
    public class Event
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Start Date")]
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("End Date")]
        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Event Details")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("User")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public void setEvent()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

a model for the database calendar entities

```
namespace TryEvents2.Models
{
    public class CalendarEntities : DbContext
    {
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

I have a home controller of the following

```
namespace TryEvents2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        CalendarEntities db = new CalendarEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult GetWEntitiesByDate(DateTime date)
        {
            var entities = db.Events.Where(x => x.Start == date.Date);
            var todaysEvents = new TodaysEventsViewModel {events = entities.ToList() };


            return PartialView("_TodaysEvents", todaysEvents);
        }


    }
}
```

I am having difficulties going from here on creating the methods necessary to CRUD the calendar events and the view that would be displaying them.  I am wanting to make the standard datepicker element bigger and have a popup window for the event detail display.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

In my few experience doing something like that is quite difficult with jquery UI datepicker. If you want a calendar to works as a datepicker and able to edit events and shows depending on the day I think the best solution for you is Arshaw Fullcalendar

[FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

This is a calendar (not a datepicker) but you can create custom events to make it works as a datepicker-calendar for your purposes. You can choose a date an render your events from a specific date. You are using MVC so for bringing the date you need JSON like this

```
public ActionResult GetEvents()
    {

       //code to return the events from DB

        return Json(evevtsObject,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
    }
```

And for the events to load on the calendar you need to call the "events" function from the calendar.

```
events: function (startdate, enddate, callback) {
            var url = "Controller/GetEvents";
            $.getJSON(url,

                function (result) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        for (i in result) {
                            var calEvent = result[i];


                            calEvent.startdate = new Date(parseInt(calEvent.startdate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                            calEvent.end = new Date(parseInt(calEvent.enddate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                        }
                    }

                    var calevents = result;


                    callback(calevents);


                });
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That does help a lot, what would some of the methods look like to return and write information to/from the database?

Comment: Well the one I write was to retrieve the "events" from database to the calendar, and displaying them like the fullcalendar home page. 1. You need a table from database with 4 columns to start: (id, startdate, enddate, extracolumn). 2. You need to create the query to the database and return json to bring the events in json format to use the fullcalendar events function to load the events into the calendar. And for creating the CRUD depends on your needs

Comment: I do have the table created with the 4 columns.  I am just having trouble with the rest, I know the entity framework allows for the automation of the CRUD methods right

Comment: Well I haven't used entity framework but I think you are right. If you manage to create a "read" operation with entity framework that return json, you will populate the calendar with your events.